# Setting up odometry on physical bot

Tags: navigation, ros2, odometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Howdy!

I'm currently making the switch from gazebo to a physical bot and realized I was using gazebo's diff drive plugin to handle publishing odom transformations.

I'm wondering how can I create a odom -> base_link transformation using ROS2 galactic for real life application. If anyone knows any examples, it would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391147/setting-up-odometry-on-physical-bot/) by [ericnasanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/87206/ericnasanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It’s a very exciting journey you will embark in understanding how to make simulations come to live.

Im sure there are many technical answers to your question. So I’ll share how I started learning as I’m self taught. Pick a commercial robot with great documentation that has a simulation package. By studying how the hardware is simulated then you develop an appreciation of what is involved

Highly recommend to study Rosbot:
https://husarion.com/tutorials/ros2-tutorials/rosbot-ros2-demo/

A tutorial using Ros2 but Foxy shows you how is done. Then study the manuals and simulation package thoroughly and you will find what makes this possible. Hope this gives you a starting point.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ericnasanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/87206/ericnasanta/) on 2021-11-18**:
Thanks! I'll look into it!